# Text normalization in JS

Tags: javascript, unicode, normalization, unicode-normalization, text-normalization

Is there any way to convert a string to [normal form C](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) in Javascript?  I know about [unorm](https://github.com/walling/unorm) in node.js, but I'm interested in in-browser JS, so reasonably standard browser APIs are ok.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no convertion algorithm available out of the box for web-browser javascript.

**EDIT**
This might be what you're looking for (but again, it's not just a function call out of the box)
http://rishida.net/blog/?p=222